# Delphi: TRegExpr

Tags: regex, delphi

The problem: need to get all the st in a string. Doing so, but in Memo is added only the last result, ie st2. How do I get st and st2, etc.?

```
const
  pattern = '<h3 class=.*><a class=.*>([a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-Я]+)</a></h3>';
var
  r: TRegExpr;
  s: string;
begin
r:=TRegExpr.Create;
s:='<h3 class="yt-lockup-ellipsize"><a class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link result-item-translation-title"dir="ltr"title="Женщины"data-sessionlink="ei=CO_0s_S3oLECFQQZ3wodxl5sKw%3D%3D"href="/watch?v=E0MzksPjObU">st1</a></h3>';
s:=s + '<h3 class="yt-lockup-ellipsize"><a class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link result-item-translation-title"dir="ltr"title="Женщины"data-sessionlink="ei=CO_0s_S3oLECFQQZ3wodxl5sKw%3D%3D"href="/watch?v=E0MzksPjObU">st2</a></h3>';
r.Expression:=pattern;
if r.Exec(s) then
  REPEAT
    Memo2.Lines.Add(r.Match[1]);
  UNTIL not r.ExecNext;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh. Parsing HTML with regexs = bad, *bad* idea.

Anyways, your regex is greedy, so the `"<h3 class=.*><a class=.*>"` part matches from your first  tag all the way through the 2nd  tag. You need to gobble stuff up only through the first ">" that's hit, so try something like `"<h3 class="[^>]*><a class="[^>]*>([a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-Я]+)</a></h3>"`. (You can also use a lazy quantifier such as, e.g., ".+?" instead of ".*", but that's slower than using the negated option.)

Note that this will not properly handle ">" embedded in a quoted attribute -- for that, you need to work much harder.

- Edit: FYI, here's the lazy quantifier version: `<h3\sclass=.+?><a\sclass=.+?>([a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-Я]+)</a></h3>` (the "\s" is the whitespace character -- much more reliable on most regex. parsers).

Really, you're much better off running this through an XML parser.

Comment: In general, HTML is not a regular language so regexs can't capture all the possible ways HTML can be written (no closing tags, etc. -- well, that would also fail XML parsing). I speak from recent experience: my little regex-based HTML parser failed to skip commented-out HTML. DUMB. 

C.f., http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html for a funny take.

Also, it's possible to feed HTML into a regex-based solution that would completely lock up the parser.

If you have a well-defined domain, you're actually probably OK. Just beware of untrusted input.

Comment: As far as good ideas go...If I had to do anything but the most simple of HTML parsing, I'd use Python for Delphi to call out to BeautifulSoup, which is just the touchstone for HTML parsers.